# Resume Cadence Workflow based on signal without blocking the thread

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

We want to build a workflow which contains below steps in that order

1. Execute some synchronous activities.
2. Trigger an external operation via kafka event.
3. Listen to the kafka events for the result of the operation.
4. Execute some other activities based on the result.

Kafka may contain events not related to workflow, so we need a separate workflow to filter the events for that particular workflow.

Using cadence I'm planning to split it into two workflows

- Workflow1 : 1 -> 2 -> wait for signal -> 4
- Workflow2 : 3 -> Call workflow1.signal

Is it possible to wait for a signal in workflow1 without actually blocking the thread, so that the thread can process another workflow in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some misunderstanding on how Temporal/Cadence works. There is no requirement to not block a thread for other workflows to be able to make progress. Worker instance will have no problem dealing with such situation.

So I would recommend to block the thread in the workflow one to wait for the signal as it is the simplest way to solve your business requirements.

As a side note I don't understand why you need a second workflow. There is no need to have a workflow to filter Kafka events. You can do it directly in a Kafka consumer that signals the first workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Maxim. I'm new to Cadence/Temporal workflows. I've just started exploring the frameworks and it seems I didn't frame my question properly (updated now).  

My question is whether we can unblock the same thread to process another workflow. Let's say we need to run 100 workflows with 10 threads.  Instead of ten threads blocked on Kafka response, can we re-use them to process other workflows in the meantime.

Yes, I was referring to Kafka consumer as second workflow.

Comment: The phrase of 100 workflow with 10 threads doesn't make sense in the context of Temporal. You can have a worker with 10 threads and 1 million workflows in your system and it is OK if most of the time they are blocked waiting for an external event.

Comment: Thanks, Maxim, for the clarification. 
I think in this scenario overall throughput will be impacted, as the threads are blocked on external event most of the time and are not able to pick another workflow in the meantime (Given that we are constrained by no. of threads per worker and need to process 1M workflows) and How can we dynamically scale workers (I mean based on which parameter) in such scenarios to improve throughput ?

Comment: Your assumption of "the threads are blocked on external event most of the time and are not able to pick another workflow" is incorrect. When workflow is blocked it can be removed from the worker memory if needed and release its threads back. When it receives a new event it is going to be resurrected on a potentially different worker and continue from the same place it was blocked on.

Comment: Awesome, well that fits into our use-case then. It would be of great help if you can share any java example depicting the scenario ------ When workflow is blocked it can be removed from the worker memory if needed and release its threads back. When it receives a new event it is going to be resurrected on a potentially different worker and continue from the same place it was blocked on ---- –

Comment: Here is an example of signal handling: https://github.com/temporalio/temporal-java-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/io/temporal/samples/hello/HelloSignal.java. No special code needed to deal with workflow passivation and activation. It is done by the framework behind the scene.

Comment: "When workflow is blocked it can be removed from the worker memory if needed and release its threads back." @MaximFateev How is that implemented Java-wise? The JVM thread executing the workflow is blocked when it does something like `await`, right? Does the Workflow engine send it an `interrupt()` when it wants the thread back?

Comment: It throws a subclass of Error. It assumes that workflow code never catches Throwable.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience writing Kafka/Kinesis consumers (not working with Cadence but plan to do so soon). My feeling is that you only need 1 consumer thread blocked and waiting for new events from the Kafka stream. And this consumer can live anywhere as long as it can talk to your Cadence system to send a signal to a workflow. For each Kafka message (after filter out non related), if it can be designed to contain all the information for the consumer to decide which workflow to signal, it will be very simple. If you have no control over what is in the message (sounds like you have an existing stream), it is a little trick. Your consumer may need to look up which workflow to call based on some other identifier in the message

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Yes, I'm planning to do exactly what you have mentioned with respect to Kafka consumer(message will contain information to decide which workflow instance to signal). But the issue is thread which is executing the actual workflow is also blocked waiting for the signal after step 2 which will impact overall throughput. Basically if I split the workflow into 2. One for executing steps 1->2 and another for step 4, it will increase the throughput. But, I want to stitch all the steps into a single workflow to track overall progress.

Comment: "thread which is executing the actual workflow": to my understanding, that is not how Cadence/Temporal works. When a workflow invoke an activity then wait for a signal, the Java/Go worker thread that was executing the workflow will move on to do other things. That "workflow" are now bunch of data in the database. When the signal comes, it goes into a queue, and a worker with capacity will pick it up and continue execution of the workflow

Comment: Thanks, Gordon, for the clarification.